# How to Copy Item at PowerShell two times (merge to destination folder)?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Good day!

I try to copy files and folders from local machine to remote host.
So, now i try to copy from one local folder to another local folder (for debugging)

```
foreach ($server in $RemoteServers) {

Write-Host 'Copy from '  $LocalServer  ' to ' $server        
Copy-Item $LocalServer $server -Force -Recurse  # copies to destinationFolder; it is OK

Write-Host 'Copy from '  $LocalServerGame ' to ' $server
Copy-Item -Path  $LocalServerGame -Destination $server -Recurse -Force  //BUT! Copies on destinationFolder/ServerGame. WHY?
}
```

First code copies well, but second copies on child folder. But i want what second copy-item merge with existing destination folder.

How to do that? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend using `robocopy`.

Comment: What are the values for $Server, $LocalServer, $LocalServerGame for the first iteration through the loop?